# C programmin WM_PAINT causes bad behavior

Tags: c, windows, winapi

I have created a parent window and it has many child windows like buttons, static texts exc. They are all visible and work without any problem but when I add piece of code to my window callback they all disappear + I can't see the line which I just tried to draw from the functions.

How do I rid of this problem?

```
case WM_PAINT:
    {
        HDC hdc = GetDC(hwnd);
        HGDIOBJ hp = CreatePen(0 ,5,RGB(0,100,0));
        SelectObject(hdc,hp);
        MoveToEx(hdc, 825, 0, 0);
        LineTo(hdc, 825, 1000);
        ReleaseDC(hwnd, hdc);
    }
break;
```

Comment: Without a good [mcve] nobody can comment definitively. But the obvious problem here is that you don't use `BeginPaint` and `EndPaint`. Various reasons for doing that. Start by changing your code to use those methods to obtain a DC. Then if you still have problems, come back with a [mcve].

Comment: Alternatively, take some advice from those of us that have been in your position before. Recognise that you have a lot to learn, and make an attempt to learn it. Get a copy of Petzold's classic. Read it carefully.

Comment: The code has a pretty bad handle leak.  That doesn't go on forever, after 10,000 paints the OS stops allowing the program to leak more.  Which is not going to take very long, it generates paints, oh, thousands of times per second because it never validates the paint region.  Every control will now misbehave when they can now no longer create drawing objects.

Answer (score 0):

1. You don't use BeginPaint/EndPaint
2. If you draw into the parent window you have to take care that you don't overwrite anything. See style WS_CLIPCHILDREN.
3. Because you are not using BeginPaint/EndPaint the background is not prepared. And if you pass the message to the default window procedure, the code there will call BeginPaint/EndPaint and this will cause the background to be erased.
4. You create a pen, select it into a DC and you never destroy the pen, Also you create a new pen every time you repaint.

Please read some books about using the Windows GDI! All I wrote can be easily fixed when you inform yourself about the basics...